# How to get photos by album name Picasa and Zend GData PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, picasa, zend-gdata

I am having trouble accessing Picasa web albums by album name. I have album name 'My Test Album'. If I use that name (including the spaces) I receive the error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Uri_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid URI supplied'

Without the spaces 'MyTestAlbum' works fine:

```
// Construct the query                      
$query = $this->photos->newAlbumQuery();
$query->setUser( "default" );
$query->setAlbumName( "MyTestAlbum" ); //This works fine
```

This causes error:

```
// Construct the query                      
$query = $this->photos->newAlbumQuery();
$query->setUser( "default" );
$query->setAlbumName( "My Test Album" ); // This causes error
```

My question is that what characters are not allowed so I can strip them out before calling `setAlbumName()`?

Or any suggestions on a better approach?

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a list of albums that match a specific name:

```
// Find the album for the given accountId.
$albumQuery = $picasa->newAlbumQuery();
$albumQuery->setUser( $user );
$albumQuery->setAlbumName( "AlbumName" ); // No spaces.
$albumQuery->setMaxResults( 1 );

$albumId = null;

try {
  $albumFeed = $picasa->getAlbumFeed( $albumQuery );

  foreach( $albumFeed as $key => $entry ) {
    $albumId = $entry->getGphotoAlbumId();
  }
}
catch( Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $ex ) {
  // Create the album because the album name could not be found.
  $albumId = $this->createAlbum( $picasa, "AlbumName" );
}
```

At this point, `$albumId` should be referencing a valid album.

The code iterates over an album feed. You will have to ensure that the album name is uniquely identified; otherwise the code will return multiple albums that match the names.

Note that if you delete an album, then recreate an album of the same name, there is a bug that prevents you from retrieving that album. See also: [List recreated album names that were previously deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352676/list-recreated-album-names-that-were-previously-deleted).